# Storm and Redis

Tags: redis, apache-storm

I am trying to solve a problem with real-time analytics. I would like to compute values in real-time. I receive streaming data and process it with Kafka and Storm and finally write it to Redis. Now I would like to push/pull all the data stored in Redis again into Storm to do further computation with it. The problem is, this must be repeated every minute. So every minute all the values from Redis have to be pulled/pushed and computed. I do not know if this is the right way to solve my problem, but I need a kind of cache. Do you have any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use druid instead. Which stores values in kafka and uses storm to insert values. It's column based storage and specially designed for real-time analytics. Redis is quick, but you can't achieve all the analytical requirements with redis, to achieve a simple group by or order by queries you need to write your own implementation logic, Whereas druid is specifically designed to serve for this purpose.

http://druid.io/

Hope this helps.